# "No schemata were loaded" jOOQ generator 3.5.0

Tags: oracle, maven, jooq

I used jOOQ 3.4.2 generator without any problem.

But with version 3.5.0 and exactly the same pom configuration, the generation doesn't work any more. I received this warning :

```
[WARNING] No schemata were loaded  : Please check your connection settings, and whether your database (and your database version!) is really supported by jOOQ. Also, check the case-sensitivity in your configured <inputSchema/> elements : [mySchema]
```

pom.xml:

```
<jdbc>
    <driver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbHostname:1521:dbServiceName</url>
    <user>user</user>
    <password>password</password>
</jdbc>
<generator>
    <name>org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator</name>
    <database>
        <name>org.jooq.util.oracle.OracleDatabase</name>
        <includes>.*</includes>
        <excludes></excludes>
        <includeExcludeColumns>false</includeExcludeColumns>
        <recordVersionFields></recordVersionFields>
        <recordTimestampFields></recordTimestampFields>
        <syntheticPrimaryKeys></syntheticPrimaryKeys>
        <overridePrimaryKeys></overridePrimaryKeys>
        <dateAsTimestamp>true</dateAsTimestamp>
        <unsignedTypes>true</unsignedTypes>
        <inputSchema>myInputSchema</inputSchema>
        <schemaVersionProvider></schemaVersionProvider>
        <outputSchemaToDefault>false</outputSchemaToDefault>
        <customTypes>
            <customType>
                <name>java.lang.Boolean</name>
                <converter>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.converter.BooleanConverter</converter>
            </customType>
        </customTypes>
        <forcedTypes>
            <forcedType>
                <name>java.lang.Boolean</name>
                <expressions>.*\.*Access.*</expressions>
            </forcedType>
        </forcedTypes>
    </database>
    <generate>
        <relations>true</relations>
        <deprecated>false</deprecated>
        <instanceFields>true</instanceFields>
        <generatedAnnotation>true</generatedAnnotation>
        <records>true</records>
        <pojos>true</pojos>
        <pojosEqualsAndHashCode>false</pojosEqualsAndHashCode>
        <immutablePojos>false</immutablePojos>
        <interfaces>false</interfaces>
        <daos>true</daos>
        <jpaAnnotations>false</jpaAnnotations>
        <validationAnnotations>false</validationAnnotations>
        <globalObjectReferences>true</globalObjectReferences>
        <fluentSetters>false</fluentSetters>
    </generate>
    <target>
        <packageName>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.generated</packageName>
        <directory>projectPath/src/main/java</directory>
    </target>
</generator>
```

Maven execution:

```
[...]
[WARNING] DEPRECATED : The configuration property /configuration/generator/database/dateAsTimestamp is deprecated as it is superseded by custom bindings and converters. It will thus be removed in the future.
[INFO] License parameters       
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]   Thank you for using jOOQ and jOOQ's code generator
[INFO]                          
[INFO] Database parameters      
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]   dialect                : ORACLE
[INFO]   URL                    : jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbHostname:1521:dbServiceName
[INFO]   target dir             : projectPath/src/main/java
[INFO]   target package         : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.generated
[INFO]   includes               : [.*]
[INFO]   excludes               : []
[INFO]   includeExcludeColumns  : false
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]                          
[INFO] DefaultGenerator parameters
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]   strategy               : class org.jooq.util.DefaultGeneratorStrategy
[INFO]   deprecated             : false
[INFO]   generated annotation   : true
[INFO]   JPA annotations        : false
[INFO]   validation annotations : false
[INFO]   instance fields        : true
[INFO]   records                : true
[INFO]   pojos                  : true
[INFO]   immutable pojos        : false
[INFO]   interfaces             : false
[INFO]   daos                   : true
[INFO]   relations              : true
[INFO]   global references      : true
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]                          
[INFO] Generation remarks       
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]   none                   
[INFO]                          
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] No schemata were loaded  : Please check your connection settings, and whether your database (and your database version!) is really supported by jOOQ. Also, check the case-sensitivity in your configured <inputSchema/> elements : [myInputSchema]
[INFO] Generating schemata      : Total: 0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.730 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-12-11T14:51:07+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/156M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you get when you execute `SELECT username FROM all_users`? Also, what's the value of `[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]` in the warning message, after *"in your configured <inputSchema/> elements"* ?

Comment: Have you gotten around to solving this issue?

Comment: Not solved yet: I'm using 3.4.2 instead of 3.5.0. I edited my question, replacing [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] with more significant values. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is that a placeholder for your actual schema name? Or what is the real schema name that you're using both in SQL (`SELECT username FROM all_users`) and in your code generation configuration?

Comment: I am facing same issue with latest trial 3.8. I can execute the query without problems on database (Select username from all_users).